Adding rules to ignore array (pa11y-ci) doesn't ignore the rules
I have "pa11y-ci": "^3.1.0" installed and added following rules in the .pa11yci to ignore the error of This element has insufficient contrast at this conformance level. Expected a contrast ratio of at least 4.5:1.
{
  "standard": "WCAG2AA",
  "level": "warning",
  "runners": [
    "axe"
  ],
  "defaults": {
    "timeout": 500000,
    "wait": 2000,
    "ignore": [
      "WCAG2AA.Principle1.Guideline1_4.1_4_3.G18",
      "WCAG2AA.Principle1.Guideline1_4.1_4_3.G18",
      "WCAG2AAA.Principle1.Guideline1_4.1_4_6.G18",
      "WCAG2AAA.Principle1.Guideline1_4.1_4_6.G18"
    ]
  },
  "urls": [
    {
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "actions": []
    }
  ]
}


But it's not ignoring the rule. What should I fix to make the ignore works?
